# Node js with redis not returning to caller

Tags: node.js, redis

I am new to Node world, but have some information of callbacks and Promises.

So just made a small code to get the data from the Redis and printing it to the console.

Now the code below is working pretty nice but it never returns it. Means that when I runs it using the node command, say **test.js** is the name of the file then it executes and returns me the value from the **Redis** server but never comes back to prompt. Please see the pic.Why is it so, what we have to do to make it return.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient(6379, "localhost");
var Promise = require("bluebird");
client.get("key1", function(err, result){
  if(err)
    throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Because the redis client has to keep connection to the server and hence binds to some event listeners. This keeps the process from exiting.

Comment: Then how do I use with other services, suppose I want to put some key in redis and have to come back. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the process. Check if you have to close redis connection first.

```
client.get("key1", function(err, result){
  if(err)
    throw err;
  console.log(result);
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: `client.quit()` should probably suffice.